# Neo4j graph visualizing libraries

Tags: graph, neo4j, visualization, libraries, cypher

Recently I explored some libraries where I can visualize graphs from Neo4j, but didn't get a clear view wich one to choose, so I have a couple thought I'd like to share.

My requirements and wishes - after search throught REST API with cypher query visualize graphs with all relationships, nodes. And result make interactive - able to drag/drop... opportunity to reveal other nodes/rels on click. Import nodes throught json data and be able to show quickly up to at least 400 elements.

So I more or less explored further libraries:

Three.js - mostly for 3D. (If I don't need 3D then better not to choose this one)

Arbor.js - drawing leaves up to you, mostly layout library

VivaGraphJS - easy to use, but almost no documentation :(

D3.js - Looks fine, but uses SVG

Cytoscape.js - looks fine, but I read that I can't use it with Neo4j.  [Is D3.js the right choice for real-time visualization of Neo4j Graph DB data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867132/is-d3-js-the-right-choice-for-real-time-visualization-of-neo4j-graph-db-data)  why?

Processing.js - have it's own language similar to Java. I'm not so much in Java-like language (yet).

And I have a couple questions:

1) Whats your experience - benefits, weakneses of libraries?

2) I suppose I want to use canvas insted of SVG? (a lot of small elements on the screen).

3) Arbor is special library for layout, but others don't have layout algorithms or what?

I'll appreciate any opinion! :-)

Comment: there's a webinar on graph visualization on Sep 5th: http://info.neotechnology.com/0905-linkurious-register.html [not sure if this is compliant to SO rules, if not please remove this comment]

Comment: You didn't specify your requirement to not use SVG upfront. Why is that.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, for large graph rendering, canvas is better to choose. (Read from various forums).

Answer (score 5):

I pondered a similar situation. I chose sigma.js.

> 1) Whats your experience - benefits, weakneses of libraries?

sigma.js is specific to graph rendering. d3 is a full on toolbox for visualization. Since I only want to draw graphs, the concise sigma.js interface was easier to work with. I think this is [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbLysxaqM2Q) where the creator talks about how sigma.js is able to do incremental rendering and thus perform better and handle more vertices/edges smoothly.

> 2) I suppose I want to use canvas insted of SVG? (a lot of small
>   elements on the screen).

sigma.js renders to the canvas.

Here are the [sigma.js examples](http://sigmajs.org/examples.html). The "hide nodes" example shows mouse interactions. Additionaly, here is a [blog post](http://www.bobbriody.com/blog/2013/06/14/storing-and-visualizing-linkedin-with-neo4j-and-sigma-js/) showing how one can easily integrate neo4j w/ sigma using a very minimal amount of data massaging code written in node.js. It would be easy to port this to any server language.

Comment: Last two links are broken...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) in that list which you might want to take a look at as it is very useful ([example](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/04/12/using-sigma-js-with-neo4j/))

You will have to somehow handle the rendering of the received data (i.e. go from a data structure to its visual representation) and this depends on what are you trying to show / say with that visualisation, how you want to do it and how you want it to look like.

As a starting point, i would go with D3 and Sigma.

Answer (score 0):

I note that Gephi is not on your list. As a standalone visualiser/editor, its the best that I have used (you just get the neo4j plugin, and it will import the source files of the database and let you view it). Its also Open Source, so you can include it as part of a project.

Comment: I tried Gephi but it has a limit on edges or nodes (maybe both, don't remember) :( Ended up with D3.js :)

Answer (score 0):

Also missing from your list is the [yFiles](https://www.yworks.com/yfiles) family of graph visualization libraries.

The JavaScript variant of if uses both Canvas, WebGL, and SVG. This can give very good performance and high-quality visualizations at the same time. For hair-ball-like graphs (thousands of dots and lines, but probably no text) you can use WebGL and Canvas and when you zoom in to actually make sense of the data, you can use SVG to get detailed high-quality visualizations with labels, icons, data-bound visualizations, etc.  You can use both techniques in the same visualization, even at the same time, benefiting from the best of both worlds ([demo](https://live.yworks.com/demos/view/largegraphs/index.html)).

[Connecting yFiles to Neo4j](https://medium.com/neo4j/neo4j-graph-visualization-like-a-pro-18651963ebd4) is easy [using the JavaScript Bolt driver](https://neo4j.com/blog/graph-visualization-neo4j-schemas-yfiles/).

Aiming at 400 elements in the view is a good idea. While larger graphs tend to look really nice, most of the time you won't gain a lot of insights by looking at "hair-balls". These almost artistic visualizations all look very similar and as such carry little to no information. Often you could just as well display a static image showing the first google image search hit for a "hairball graph" query :-)

In order to better support the user during exploration, filtering, grouping, nesting, and dynamic interaction should be added to the viewer application. How this can be implemented, very much depends on the business domain in the visualization, though and there are only very few generic approaches that work for generic graphs.

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates the above mentioned visualization library. I do not represent it on SO, though.</sup>