# How to visualise Neo4j graph database created from an embedded Neo4j java application

Tags: neo4j

I created an application which embedded Neo4j. In that application I created and stored some nodes with some relationships. My application has saved this database to a file. I would like to visualise that data. I know I can see graphs if I fire up the Neo4j server but I do not know how to import my neo4j.db file into the Neo4j server so that I can visualise it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To make the Neo4j server use your own db, just edit the `conf/neo4j-server.propereties` file, set the `org.neo4j.server.database.location=/path/to/your/database.db` property and fire it up with `./bin/neo4j start`.

Comment: For general visualization info check this page: http://neo4j.org/develop/visualize and especially the articles from Max de Marzi http://maxdemarzi.com

Comment: @MichaelHunger the visualization link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case you might have different solutions:

- Use a web-based visualization
- Use a desktop application to visualize your data

#### Use web-based visualization

In this case you have to take care of the web-app to visualize the data.
You have basically two solutions out there: Javascript or Java applets.

For the Javascript side you have many choices: [D3js](http://d3js.org/), [VivaGraph](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS), [SigmaJS](http://sigmajs.org/), [KeyLines](http://keylines.com/).
The first three are open source and free while the last one has a commercial licence and non-free.
There're already a million questions about these libraries on SO, so I'll link you to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867132/is-d3-js-the-right-choice-for-real-time-visualization-of-neo4j-graph-db-data/23522907#23522907) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772701/neo4j-visualisation-manipulate-the-graph/22782859#22782859) [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964056/graph-visualization-frameworks/21966492#21966492) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825302/data-visualization-libraries/21828572#21828572) understand the various differences.

#### Desktop Application

The main solutions in this case I would recommend you, depending on the kind of data are: either [Gephi](https://gephi.org) or [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org).
In both cases I believe you have to write your own adapter to communicate with your application.

#### Architecture Reference

The architecture in both cases will be the following:

- The controller renders a webpage with the JS visualisation framework you want to use
- The controller offers a couple of JSON endpoints the client can use to query the data from the Neo4J embedded
- Each query fetch the data, put in a model and render the JSON to send to the client

Comment: I have used D3 before but with my data structure in JSON format. When I look at the Neo4j database file, I have no idea how and where it has structured the data; it's just a series of folders. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: You can still use the embedded Neo4J to query the data, without exporting the raw folders outside the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're NOT using neo4j 2.0+ then really good way to visualize your graph is by using neoclipse. https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse/downloads
it's really handy and it has cypher support too.

Or

another quick hack is to copy your db folder (which you created by using embedded database) into $NEO4j_HOME/data/

and

change $NEO4j_HOME/conf/neo4j-server-properties file to point to

and

start your server (bin/.neo4j start). You'll be able to visualize your database at localhost:7474
I hope it helps!