# Cant see any graphs in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I just installed the latest version of Neo4J on ubuntu 15.04 and on my application code I have provided the path for the database as the following :

```
GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("/home/aimad/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb");
```

When I type `match(n) return n;` on console of `http://localhost:7474` I cant see any graph.

And I notice that the location of the database is : `/home/aimad/neo4j-community-2.3.0/data/graph.db` on the Neo4j plateform.

I also tried to change the location of the database in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` but I got this error message when I want to start neo4j :

> Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user process [3151]...
>   waiting for server to be ready... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
>   Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What is in the logs?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen how can I see the logs ?

Comment: You dont need to change, the error is telling you that the logs contain the reason why the db wont start

Comment: It seems that you are trying to start two databases, one embedded and one standalone on the same db. This is impossible. In the log you should find an issue related to lock

Answer (score 2):

As @AllessandroNegro indicated, you cannot start a neo4j server on the same DB that is already opened by an embedded app.

If you want to visualize the DB used by your embedded app, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922705/how-to-visualise-neo4j-graph-database-created-from-an-embedded-neo4j-java-applic) might be helpful.