# Possible to visualize neo4j graph in ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js, neo4j

I'm quite novice to neo4j. I would like to find out if I can query a neo4j database from a ruby on rails application and use the result to make a graph visualization in my application. I have looked at d3.js, that problably can do it. I would just like to know if it possible to use GraphGist in a ruby on rails application and make a graph visualization as can be seen  [here](http://gist.neo4j.org/). If I can use GraphGist where can I find more information how to use in a ruby on rails project? If I cannot use GraphGist would d3.js be a good choice of vizualizing neo4j graphs in a Ruby on Rails project?

Comment: Doesn't neo4j come with its own d3.js visualiation frontend? http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/

Comment: Maybe they use it in the http://localhost:7474/browser/, but I want to represent a visualization of a graph pattern into my web page that is similiar to or exactly the same graph representation as there is in `http://localhost:7474/browser/`

Comment: There are already several SO questions and answers about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772701/neo4j-visualisation-manipulate-the-graph/22782859#22782859 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893401/interactive-and-dynamic-graph-visualization/21907330#21907330 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867132/is-d3-js-the-right-choice-for-real-time-visualization-of-neo4j-graph-db-data/23522907#23522907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple single html page Neo4j console that you can use to learn how do to it.

The master branch uses the alchemy.js library http://jexp.github.io/cy2neo

And the neod3 branch uses the visualization from the graphgist project.

If you clone it locally and check out that branch and run the file in a browser you should be able to see the visualization.

Comment: nice! thank you very much. I would see if I can use it on my website

Comment: Otherwise you can also check out the ruby code examples listed on http://neo4j.com/developer/ruby those also support d3.js visualizations.